# Using mgcv gam() and gtsummary tbl_uvregression()

Tags: gtsummary

How do we specify a smoothing spline fit for certain variables in `tbl_uvregression()` with `method = gam`?

```
data %>% 
 select(outcome, predictors) %>% 
 tbl_uvregression(
   method = gam,
   y = outcome,
   method.args = list(family = binomial),
   exponentiate = T)
```

For example if I want to indicate s(x1) in the gam model formula for variable x1, how do we add that in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wrap the variable in a function, like `s()` in `tbl_uvregression()`. You will need to construct the individual tables with `tbl_regression()`, then stack them on top of one another.  Code example below! But, it is a bit strange because the smoothed terms don't have a single odds ratio....so you're just getting a table of p-values....

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.1'
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'nlme'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     collapse
#> This is mgcv 1.8-35. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.


tbl_uv <-
  tibble(variable = c("age", "marker")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    # build reg models
    tbl = 
      glue::glue("response ~ s({variable})") %>%
      as.formula() %>%
      gam(data =  trial, family = binomial) %>%
      tbl_regression() %>%
      list()
  ) %>%
  # stack the regression tables
  pull() %>%
  tbl_stack()
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>